# Provide Data from mysql using a search field in a form

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

i use a crm on a wordpress website. I'm trying to make a search field where a user can enter a number and with that number he/she should be able to see certain data from the database that is connected with the number that is entered.

What i got so far is:

```
<?php
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'my user name';
   $dbpass = 'my password';

   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Kan geen connectie maken: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $sql = 'SELECT lead_content FROM wp_wgbsupicrm_leads';
   mysql_select_db('my database name');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Kan geen gegevens vinden: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      echo "EMP ID :{$row['lead_content']}  <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
   }

   echo "Gegevens ontvangen\n";

   mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

This will give me a result of:

```
resultaat:{"zoeknummer":"554477","komplex":"test
   4","plaats":"84","versturen":null} 

   resultaat:{"zoeknummer":"556478","komplex":"test
   3","plaats":"51","versturen":null} 

   resultaat:{"zoeknummer":"112255","komplex":"test
   2","plaats":"12","versturen":null} 

   resultaat:{"zoeknummer":"110022","komplex":"Test
   1","plaats":"1","versturen":null}
```

What i want is a search field where the "zoeknummer" is entered and the "komplex" & "plaats" are shown. the "versturen" isn't needed to be shown.

This is an image of the database where i need to get the information from:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX3XD.png)

To get this far i spended 1 and a half day.. I know i'm a total starter at this all, i have a basic html and css.. But i'm trying to learn more and hope with some assistance here i can get this to work, and in the mean time learn how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should know how to use WHERE clause in your SQL query. this is mainly used for search purposes. 
In your HTML form, give the textfield a name such as: name="$data"
Then in your SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT lead_content FROM wp_wgbsupicrm_leads' where lead_content='$data'";
```

Then the search will give you only the data you want from the text field you entered.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for helping. So if i replace '$data' with the expected number they should type like '110022' i should retrieve that information?

I tried this and i get a htp error 500 So i think i haven't used it the right way?

'code'  $sql = 'SELECT lead_content FROM wp_wgbsupicrm_leads WHERE lead_content='110022';

Comment: yes, then it will show only that row which has lead_content as 110022. but remember using quotes means you are using a string. for numbers, donot use quotes

Comment: your code isnt working because you didnt use the quotes correctly. there are three ' used which will always result in an error

Comment: Ok i tried this:

<code>$sql = 'SELECT lead_content FROM wp_wgbsupicrm_leads WHERE lead_content=110022;</code>

and it resulted in a error page

Comment: put ' after 110022 and before ; to close your query as well

Comment: That solved the error indeed, thanks. Now i do only get the echo "gegevens ontvangen\n" But no results. 

Maybe becouse the data in that field is more then just the number?

The value of the lead_content : {"zoeknummer":"11022","komplex":"test 4","plaats":"84","versturen":null}

So i want to text box to be filled in with what is behind zoeknummer, and as eche give what's behdin komplex and plaats.

Comment: make sure your database is connected and as it is case-sensitive so be sure it matches the database name

Comment: Hey Faizan, that all works perfect, when i run the script without the WHERE in it i get all 4 the result in the database as shown above. I understand the WHERE defines a value in the lead_content.. 

The issue now is to be able to put in a value (in a search box) that is only a part of the full value in lead_content. And the result that should be used as echo are 2 other value's that are inside that full value from lead_content.

Comment: if you are using html form then i already told you the answer.

Comment: <input type="text" name="name" value="">
use the "name" from the form and use this query:

    $sql = "SELECT lead_content FROM wp_wgbsupicrm_leads' where lead_content='$data'";

Comment: I think i've done what you suggested, but it results in an error: <form method="post"> <input type="text" name="zoeknummer" value=""/> <input type="submit" name="Zoek" value="Zoek" onclick="" /> </form> $sql = 'SELECT lead_content FROM wp_wgbsupicrm_leads WHERE lead_content=$_POST["zoeknummer"]'; mysql_select_db('mydatabase'); $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ); if(! $retval ) {die('Kan geen gegevens vinden: ' . mysql_error());} while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {echo "EMP ID :{$row['lead_content']} <br> ".;

Comment: Hello

I think i'm getting a bit further in what i want as result.

For now i have a field where a number can be entered, without a number there is no output, with a number i get the whole list of data in that column. Now from what i read is that i need to get those 4 objects in there to be split in 'array's'? so the entered number in the search field can look for the right match and then 'echo' the other objects in that lead i want to be shown. But there i'm blown away. I get the info on the screen, but how to make array's and what they are is not clear to me yet